# Spectrograph Arrangement, Noise, and Fourier Domain

Tags: telescope, astrophysics, spectroscopy, spectra

If the transform of a line profile extends out to the Nyquist frequency such that we cannot see the noise level, what could we change in our spectrograph arrangement that would allow us to see the noise level in the Fourier domain?

Comment: I am voting to close because I don't think this is a question about astronomy per se, but rather about signal processing.

Comment: There are [almost 200 Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) to choose from! This question doesn't really have any astronomy in it, it's purely about math and signal processing. There is in fact a [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com) site but first check out/search existing questions to see if this has been answered there, or if you can refer to previous questions and answers and explain how this one is different/ *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*